# Does any exchange provide API to call callback function on each transaction?

Tags: exchanges, api, automation, price-discovery, ticker

Does any exchange provide API to call callback function on each transaction?

I would like to build a auto trade platform based on the tick event, but instead of pulling the price, I would like to use the push mechanism.

Comment: you mean such as websocket?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After some search, I think pyalgotrade is closest to what I am looking for. I post answer to my own question in case someone has the same question. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It is not common to have Push APIs for Exchange sites. However Poloniex has WAMP (Web Application Messaging Protocol) over WebSocket for ticker:

https://poloniex.com/support/api/